# Find points within a circle using hibernate Spatial criteria - distanceWithin

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spatial, spatial-query, hibernate-spatial

I have a domain object `car`. One of the car properties is `location` stored in MySQL as spatial type `Point` (`columnDefinition` can't be of `Geometry`, throws an exception).

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
@Column(name = "location", columnDefinition="Point")
private Point location;
```

Using hibernate spatial criteria I would like to get those that are in a certain radius. In native sql I could use `ST_Distance_Sphere`, but I would like to use criteria instead. The problem is, that this gives me an error `org.hibernate.HibernateException: dwithin function not supported by this dialect`:

```
final Point circleCenterPoint = 
new GeometryFactory().createPoint(new Coordinate(latitude,longitude));

(...).add(SpatialRestrictions.distanceWithin(Car.LOCATION, circleCenterPoint, radiusInKm * 0.009));
```

I am using: `jts-1.13`, `hibernate-core-4.3.4`, `hibernate-spatial-4.3` (according to [that](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/), they should match) as well as `org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatial56Dialect`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is simply that the function ST_Distance_Sphere is not supported in Hibernate Spatial version 4.x (or version 5.x for that matter).

I created a ticket (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12229) to update the MySQL Spatial dialects and add support for these newer functions. These changes will not be backported to version 4.x, however.

Comment: Right, but actually I could use different approach. Use `within` function and as a polygon pass a circle (linearring). Using Mr. Ian Turton approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249945/how-to-use-geometricshapefactory-in-geotools-to-create-a-circle-on-map

But actually his `bufferPoint` method gives me a wierd circle (left a comment), do you think there is an easier way to generate a ring (in polygon) in order to use `within` function ?

I could use `GeometricShapeFactory` but not sure about `setSize()` (radius) units (and if it consider earth as a sphere during calculations)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround to "dwithin function not supported by this dialect",  I added dwithin function as below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `dwithin`(`pt1` POINT, `pt2` POINT, `radius` FLOAT) RETURNS tinyint(1)
 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE dist FLOAT;
 SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(pt1, pt2) INTO dist;
 RETURN dist<radius;
END
```