# Querydsl and MySQL - distancesphere does not exist

Tags: mysql, querydsl, hibernate-spatial

I'm using QueryDSL v4.1.4 with Spring Boot and Hibernate 5.

My goal is to perform a query based on `ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE` Function, to query results based on distance from a starting point.

I have the following query:

```
where
     .and(
         QAddress.address.geoPoint.point.distanceSphere(
               ExpressionUtils.toExpression(GeocoderUtils.geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude)))
         ).loe(distance)
     );
```

Where `QAddress.address.geoPoint.point` is a JTS Point, and `geometryFactory` has a SRID = 4326 and `PrecisionModel.maximumPreciseValue`

The resulting exception in MySQL (and also H2 with orbisgis) is:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION schemaname.distancesphere does not exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

Extra:

```
    application.yml: 
    database-platform: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL5InnoDBSpatialDialect

    build.gradle
    compile group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-jpa', version: '4.1.4'
    compile group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-sql', version: '4.1.4'
    compile group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-sql-spatial', version: '4.1.4'
    compile group: 'com.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-sql-spring', version: '4.1.4'
    compile("com.vividsolutions:jts:1.13")
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:${hibernate_version}"
    compile 'com.bedatadriven:jackson-datatype-jts:2.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.orbisgis', name: 'h2gis', version: '1.4.0'
    testCompile('com.h2database:h2:1.4.196')
    testCompile group: 'org.opengeo', name: 'geodb', version: '0.8'
    ... and so on
```

Ps. Using a query created by the EntityManager, using `st_distance_sphere`, the query is executed normally, indicating that MySQL is correctly configured to process Geo functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how QueryDSL translates the query. In any case **Hibernate Spatial does not currently support** the `st_distance_sphere` function.

Comment: Thanks! Now I found another question that indicates your open issue at hibernate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343371/find-points-within-a-circle-using-hibernate-spatial-criteria-distancewithin